# Upgrade from ubuntu 15.10 to 16.04 is stuck

Tags: upgrade, 15.10, 16.04

I have been running the upgrade from 15.10 to 16.04 for 10 hours now and it is stuck on the following screen:

[image: screen]

Also, I can not open the terminal to with the small arrow to see what is going on. Any help appreciated.

Comment: If it helps, I was running a 4.5.0 custom kernel prior to the upgrade.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming it ran into a dependency issue or conflict and locked up or crashed :(... not much now you can do but reboot

You can maybe try to go to advanced options in the grub menu and choose recovery mode .. then get to command prompt and use

`sudo apt-get install -f`

to try to fix any package problems before you try to boot again. Hopefully you will be able to boot and try the upgrade again

Comment: I managed to kill the process of the update and it seems no damage was done. Right now I tried to reboot into the regular kernel of 15.10 and do the upgrade from there.

Comment: good luck hopefully it will run without locks this time :)

Answer (score 1):

First it is necessary to kill the process which is stuck (using `htop` search for `distupgrade`). Then boot to the regular kernel of ububtu 15.10 from grub. After that run:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

This is what worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have been running the upgrade from ubuntu 14.04 lts to 16.04 and I had the same problem. I spent a lot of time searching for a solution and then I just force stop my laptop from the power button and follow the instructions from here:

Rescuing an Interrupted Ubuntu Upgrade

[This is what worked for me.](https://administratosphere.wordpress.com/2011/11/02/rescuing-an-interrupted-ubuntu-upgrade/)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that only the GUI is stuck, which is what it was in my case. I went into command line mode by CTRL +SHIFT +F1 and logged in from there. I could see in top command output that dpkg was taking 80% CPU, but it meant that it was running fine. I killed of other processes like Firefox, Nautilus  from here to free up RAM. I decided to wait a little. And sure enough , after a while GUI came out of the freeze.